# How to integrate $\int \frac{\sin^2 x \cos^2 x}{(\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x)^2} \, dx$?

Tags: integration

How to find

> $$\int \frac{\sin^2 x \cos^2 x}{(\sin^3 x+\cos^3 x)^2} \, dx.$$

I have tried but not been able to find a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: (1) What have you tried? Share your own effort and indicate where exactly you need help. (2) Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: thank you zipirovich for pointing out, I will definitely try to learn math jax and keep in mind to explain my effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{(\sin^3x+\cos^3x)^2}=\dfrac{\sin^2x\cos^2x}{\cos^6x(\tan^3x+1)^2}=\dfrac{\tan^2x\sec^2x}{(\tan^3x+1)^2}$$

Set $\tan^3x+1=u$

Comment: thanks lab bhattacharjee, I have tried it so many times but this didn't came in my mind.

Comment: one typo though that 1+tan^2x written there is by mistake.

Comment: @golushailuoo7, Thanks